# How to declare a constant Guid in C#?

Tags: c#, constants, guid, compile-time-constant

Is it possible to declare a constant Guid in C#?

I understand that I can declare a `static readonly Guid`, but is there a syntax that allows me to write `const Guid`?

Comment: What's wrong with a static readonly Guid?

Comment: Nothing, if it's the only way to do it.

Comment: @Pedro, a const is evaluated at compile-time, a static is evaluated at run-time.

Comment: pretty close: [why-cant-structs-be-declared-as-const](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590796/why-cant-structs-be-declared-as-const)

Comment: As some of the answers point out there is currently no way to make a Guid const.  ProVega's answer using a const string to me is probably best answer.  I don't like his property usage but I would create a static readonly Guid based on the string.  Main advantage is you can use Guid's normally with the one exception being a switch statement.  At that point you could use the const string member.  switch statement is only occasion that I've ran into where static readonly doesn't work.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

No. The `const` modifier only applies to "primitive" types (bool, int, float, double, long, decimal, short, byte) and strings. Basically anything you can declare as a literal.

Comment: It's actually defined the other way around.  You can use `const` for any compile time literal values.  C# doesn't actually define the term "primitive type"; it's technically just slang.  Other languages use actually define the term "primitive types" and have a fixed list of such types.  In fact, there is a single compile time literal for `Guid`, and that is `default(Guid)`.  That is the only compile time literal for Guid though.

Answer (score 59):

Declare it as `static readonly Guid` rather than `const Guid`

Comment: I believe this is the best answer because it is the only one that provides an alternative without changing the final result, the static readonly can be used in the same way of a const, including intellisense

Comment: @Raffaeu: It's a very useful posting (+1 from me), but technically, it does not even answer the question ("Is it possible to declare a constant Guid in C#?"), nor does it give any explanation on *why* the answer is yes or no. It provides a workaround, but does not explain how `static readonly` differs from `const`, and what the implication are of using one instead of the other. Thus, it's far from what a "best answer" should look like.

Answer (score 46):

```
public static readonly Guid Users = new Guid("5C60F693-BEF5-E011-A485-80EE7300C695");
```

and that's that.

Comment: It is however a suitable alternative.

Comment: It's not a suitable alternative if you need something that is evaluated at compile time.

Comment: A usecase of this not being constant would be **START CODE** 

    public static readonly Guid defaultGuid = new Guid("5C60F693-BEF5-E011-A485-80EE7300C695");
    protected bool (Guid userID = defaultGuid);
    {
        return false;
    }

**END CODE** wouldn't compile. as the guid isn't a compile time constant

Answer (score 22):

While you can't seem to do that you can do that to be parsed whenever you need it:

```
const string _myGuidStr = "e6b86ea3-6479-48a2-b8d4-54bd6cbbdbc5";
```

Comment: @ZarShardan They're one of a kind!

Comment: I used them, what u gonna do about it?

Answer (score 7):

I am doing it like this:

```
public static class RecordTypeIds
{
    public const string USERS_TYPEID = "5C60F693-BEF5-E011-A485-80EE7300C695";
    public static Guid Users { get { return new Guid(EntityTypeIds.USERS_TYPEID); } }
}
```

Comment: you'll get marginally better performance with a readonly field instead of a property that creates a new Guid for every access

Comment: I like your answer the best minus the get property.  I agree with smartcaveman...just make that a public static readonly Guid.

Comment: Ohh and only reason I like this the best is that it allows the string to be used in switch statement.  All other places I use the static readonly Guid.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want a const for.

If you want to have a known GUID that you can reuse as needed, the above solution of storing the GUID as a string and parsing to GUID as needed works.

If you need a default parameter value, that won't work.  The alternative is to use a nullable Guid and use null as your constant value.

```
public void Foo(string aParameter, Guid? anOptionalGuid = null)
```