# Expression tree yields Argument exception

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

I have the following piece of code, all works well until I get to the very last line where it fails with the following exception:

> Method 'Boolean Contains(System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression)' declared on type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression]' cannot be called with instance of type 'System.Guid'

```
var filter = new List<SomeObj> { new SomeObj { Id = "<guid-string>" }};

var lookupExpression = filter.SetOperand.Select(x => Expression.Constant(Guid.Parse(x.Id))).ToList();
var arrayOfValues = Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof(Guid), lookupExpression);
var arrayType = lookupExpression.GetType();
var containsMethod = arrayType.GetMethod("Contains");

var right = Expression.Call(dataProperty, containsMethod, arrayOfValues);
```

I think the problem is that dataProperty is read from a dynamically constructed expression which would always be a Guid so when the method executes, it sees this object as a Guid while the method and list are both List. Is there some other way around this?

Comment: The `Guid` data type cannot be `const`, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926573/how-to-declare-a-constant-guid-in-c

Comment: You can't call `filter.Contains(guid)` either way. But `filter.Any(f => f.Id == guid)`.

Comment: @abatishchev how do you recommend I convert this to a List<Expression> filter.SetOperand.Select(x => Expression.Constant(Guid.Parse(x.Id))); Which is required for Epression.NewArrayInit. Or are you recommending a totally different approach?

Comment: What is the type of `SomeObj.id`? Is it string containing guid or System.Guid?

Comment: You can also use `filter.Select(f => f.id).Contains(guid)` but it would be less efficient I think.

Comment: SomeObj.Id is a System.Guid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite understand what are you trying to do or why, but here is my *guess* how to fix your code:

1. You don't want to check that your collection of *expressions of GUIDs* (`lookupExpression`) contains a given GUID, you want to check that your expression of *collection of GUIDs* (`arrayOfValues`) does. This means that `arrayType` is wrong, it should be: `var arrayType = arrayOfValues.Type;`.
2. If `arrayOfValues` is actually meant to be array, you can't use a `Contains` instance method, because array doesn't have one.

   You can either use LINQ `Contains`, or change `arrayOfValues` to be an expression that represents `List<Guid>` instead of `Guid[]`. I have chosen LINQ.

   To get the LINQ `Contains` method, you can use LINQ:

   ```
   var containsMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods()
       .Single(m => m.Name == "Contains" && m.GetParameters().Length == 2)
       .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Guid));
   ```
3. Your `Call()` is in the wrong order even for `List.Contains()`. For LINQ `Contains`, the correct order is:

   ```
   Expression.Call(containsMethod, arrayOfValues, dataProperty)
   ```

Comment: I strongly suspected this would be the case as I have since juggled my code around to almost look like what you have here but this has answered all the nagging questions I had. I will try it when I get in. Thanks