# Is there a way to declare Guid.Empty as a constant? C#

Tags: c#, guid

Out of curiosity, Is there a way to declare Guid.Empty, nay any Guid as const? I once thought all value types can be declared as a constant.

Line below returns the error: **CS0283  The type 'Guid' cannot be declared const**

```
const Guid myConstGuid = Guid.Empty;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926573/how-to-declare-a-constant-guid-in-c

Comment: Constant values should be "known" at compile time.

Comment: [const (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/const): *Constants can be numbers, Boolean values, strings, or a null reference.*

Comment: Why you need a constant ?`Guid.Empty` already plays a role of readonly value.

Answer (score 1):

The `const` modifier is only valid for primitive types.

You could however declare it as `readonly`.