# Why can I declare const structures in C++/CLI, but not in C#?

Tags: c#, struct, c++-cli, constants, value-type

I already have found useful answers why it shouldn't be possible at all:
[Why does C# limit the set of types that can be declared as const?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441420/why-does-c-sharp-limit-the-set-of-types-that-can-be-declared-as-const)
[Why can't structs be declared as const?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590796/why-cant-structs-be-declared-as-const/4590831#4590831)
The first one has a detailed answer, which I still have to re-read a couple of times until I fully get it.
The second one has a very easy and clear answer (like *'the constructor might do anything, so it had to be run and evaluated at compile time'*).
But both refer to C#.

However, I am using C++/CLI and have a

```
value class CLocation
{
public:
  double x, y, z;

  CLocation ( double i_x, double i_y, double i_z) : x(i_x), y(i_y), z(i_z) {}
  CLocation ( double i_all) : x(i_all), y(i_all), z(i_all) {}

  ...
}
```

where I can easily create a

```
const CLoc c_loc (1,2,3);
```

which indeed is immutable, meaning 'const'.

**Why?**

`CLocation` furthermore has a function

```
System::Drawing::Point CLocation::ToPoint ()
{
  return System::Drawing::Point (x_int, y_int);
}
```

which works well on `CLocation`, but doesn't on a `const CLocation`. I think this comes from the limitation in C# (known from the links above), which likely comes from the underlying IL, so C++/CLI is affected by that limitation in the same way.

Is this correct?
Is there a way to run this member function on a `const CLocation`?

Comment: The ToPoint() function is a const violation, it is not a const function.  C++/CLI supports const when it can, it is imperfect because .NET metadata does not allow expressing it everywhere it is valid in C++.  Like on a function, the [modopt] it has to use is not valid on methods.  Use `initonly` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You must indicate to the compiler that your function doesn't change the object by adding `const` after the argument list.

Your function may then be called on a `const` variable, but may not modify its fields.

Pay also attention that some keywords (including `const` and `struct`) have different meanings in C# and C++ (and other languages based on C).

**Update**

As CPP/CLI doesn't allow a `const` modifier on a member function, you'll have to copy the variable to a non-`const` one to be able to call any member function (on the copy).

Comment: tried that already. declaring `System::Drawing::Point ToPoint () const;` produces: error C3842: 'ToPoint': Die Qualifizierer 'const' und 'volatile' für Memberfunktionen von verwalteten Typen werden nicht unterstützt. (englisch original message from MSDN: 'function': 'const' and 'volatile' qualifiers on member functions of WinRT or managed types are not supported)