# Is there a good way to make runtime constants within methods in C#?

Tags: c#, struct, constants, final, readonly

I really enjoy how in Java, we can declare variables "final" within methods to indicate that they will not change after initialization. In C#, you cannot do this same thing-- the only options are const (only works for primitives) and readonly (only works for fields declared outside of methods), neither of which I want.

I've discovered I can do something akin to the following to make a pseudo-final struct:

```
public readonly struct Final<T> {
    public readonly T Value;

    public Final(T val) {
        Value = val;
    }


    public static implicit operator T(Final<T> final) => final.Value;
    public static implicit operator Final<T>(T val) => new Final<T>(val);
}
```

Here's my issue: I want to be able to use this Final struct and treat it as if all I have is the datatype it's storing. For example, assume I have a class which stores 2D vectors called Vector2, with an x and y parameter. I would want to be able to write something like this:

```
Final<Vector2> rightVec = new Vector2(3.0f, 0.0f);
int yComponent = rightVec.y
```

However, I can't do the above. Instead, I'd have to write something like this:

```
Final<Vector2> rightVec = new Vector2(3.0f,0.0f);
int yComponent = rightVec.Value.y // <-- I don't want to have to write "Value"!
```

So this brings me to my questions. First, is there a way to do what I want? Second, is there a better method to do what I want than with structs? Third, is it even a good idea to try to do this?

Comment: Why do you feel you need to declare a local variable `readonly` anyway? What does it gain you? Fields have a performance benefit, as well as helping a lot of invariant analysis and static analysis, but what does local variables help?

Comment: Directly, no. C# does not support this kind of implicit delegation or forwarding, where accessing a member of Final<T> would automatically translate to accessing a member of T. Your Final<T> struct encapsulates T, and any attempt to access members of T requires going through the encapsulating entity, which in your case is the .Value property.

Comment: But this is not final, you can still reassign its value later: `rightVec = new Vector2(1f, 2f);` Using readonly fields should be the best for now.

Comment: The only case I could see this being helpful would be to prevent a mutable struct from being mutable. But structs should probably be immutable anyway, so the cases where this would be useful seem rare.

Comment: @shingo Ah, I suppose you're right. It wouldn't really be immutable, that makes sense. The struct itself is immutable but I could simply assign it to a different struct... I suppose my method does not come close to working for what I want to achieve.

Comment: @Charlieface Firstly, it doesn't matter :> I'm asking how to do something, it doesn't matter what I want to use it for. Secondly, I really enjoy knowing that some of my fields in methods cannot change. It makes it much easier for me to read & understand code I write, especially after long gaps in writing. I like functional programming & try to incorporate it as much as possible, and the "final" keyword in java helps a lot with that.

Comment: I guess the real answer is to break up your functions more. Because a parameter passed by value anyway can't be changed by the called function, and functions should really be short enough that they fit on your screen so you can see it all at once.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't structs be declared as const?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590796/why-cant-structs-be-declared-as-const)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There's no way in C# to prevent re-assignment of a locally declared variable inside a method, if that's what you're after.

You also ask if there's a "better" approach to what you're looking for. I think the closest you will find in C# is the `init` keyword:

```
public readonly struct Vector
{
    public Vector()
    {
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
    }

    public Vector(double x, double y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double x { get; init; }
    public double y { get; init; }
}


Vector2 rightVec = new Vector2(3.0f, 0.0f);
int yComponent = (int)rightVec.y;
```

Properties with `init` instead of `set` can only be changed in their constructor or when first constructed by the caller and can never change thereafter. This allows you to create a `struct` with initially assigned values that can't even be changed by other members. (It's similar to `get` with no `set`, and to `readonly` fields, but both of those approaches require a parameterized constructor, so `init` lets you do it a little more cleanly).

Comment: The question is specifically about local variables, not fields or properties.

Comment: Well it's obviously impossible to do with local variables so as I said this was the closest I could conceive of. If you have a better idea by all means share it.

Comment: @EmperorEto Not quite what I was going for but I didn't know about the init keyword, thanks!
Though... I should say it's not "obviously impossible." Maybe obvious to you who has done this for a while! It comes across as condescending when you say it like that... It's definitely not obvious to me that what I want to do is impossible in C#, because these features exist in other languages I've used :>

Comment: @LukeSiegel I'm sorry my "obvious" comment was in response to Etienne de Martel's comment not to you. Incidentally (unrelated) I just revised my answer a bit.

Comment: @LukeSiegel anyway if you found it useful would appreciate if you'd accept. Unless you're still hoping for a closer solution to come along but I'm pretty confident this is the best you can do in C#.

Answer (score 3):

Don't consider `final` locals as a feature. Opposed to read-only fields or constants, that are introduced to optimize compiled code, `final` locals were introduced to overcome a short coming of the Java engine (design mistakes).
Java later had issues implementing lambdas (or closures in general). In particular the case when lambdas (aka anonymous classes) capture local variables.

Although we have to differentiate between read-only `final` (Java) or `readonly` (C#) and constant `static final` (Java) or `const` (C#), it's important to note that C# does support local constants:

**C#**

```cs
public void SomeMethod()
{
  const int number = 1234;

  // Compiler error
  number = 0;
}
```

Locals defined as `final` (read-only) don't offer any relevant performance improvement except for really rare edge cases (like string concatenation, where there already exist more efficient alternative solutions like string builders). For *fields* it does as the compiler can statically evaluate values at compiletime and choose to inline them.
In fact, while compiletime constants do enable performance optimizations Java doesn't support them. However, C# supports local compiletime constants via the `const` keyword.

In addition, having read-only *fields* (class or in stance variables) allows a type to be defined as immutable. For locals this is irrelevant - especially in the pass-by-value context of Java.
C#, in contrast to Java, allows explicit pass-by-reference.
In this context a `final` local e.g. a read-only method parameter would absolutely make sense to prevent the reference from being overwritten by the consumer. C# has the `in` keyword for this case.

**C#**

```cs
public void SomeMethod(in int number)
{
  // Compiler error
  number = 12;
}
```

As we can see, using the `in` keyword allows us to achieve a similar effect: read-only local variables. For this reason, I would consider this an equivalent to Java's `final` local (from the usage point of view in terms of read-only locals and not in terms of the original purpose of `final` locals or compiler details).

I don't think there is any justification for read-only locals in C# from a compiler perspective. You *may* find it beneficial from a static analyzer perspective (for this purpose the keyword would have to be used sparingly). However, there are better ways in my opinion that allow for read-only variables and provide compiler and static analyzers support, in both languages.

The way you are thinking of a `final` local variable (which is not what the keyword `final` was designed for) is to define a read-only value that is guaranteed to not change. From that point of view (and not from the closure point of view!) declaring a constant field is the exact same. Therefore, I would consider C# `const` an equivalent to `final` local variables in Java (only in terms of read-only values!):

**Java**

```java
class MyClass {

  // Constants: more powerful than final locals in many aspects
  // e.g., compiler optimizations like inlining 
  // or readability improvements like grouping constant values 
  // in one place to know them at a glance and change them in one place etc.
  private static final int NUMBER_OF_REPEATS = 8;

  public void DoSomething() {

    // This variable is "constant" but redefined on every method call.
    // Why not make it a static field and allow the compiler 
    // to perform statical optimizations like inlining?
    final int numberOfRepeats = 8;
  
    // Instead of...
    int repeatCount = 0;
    while (repeatCount++ < numberOfRepeats) {
    }
  
    // ...you may use a constant like below. 
    // Compare the readability: it's instantly obvious that 
    // NUMBER_OF_REPEATS is a constant value, by the naming convention alone 
    // - without having to read the variable definition to identify the 'final' keyword.
    int repeatCount = 0;
    while (repeatCount++ < MyClass.NUMBER_OF_REPEATS) {

    }
  }
}
```

**C#**
The C# equivalent (in terms of a read-only variable!).

```cs
class MyClass
{
  // More powerful than final locals in many aspects
  // e.g., compiler optimizations like inlining 
  // or readability improvements like grouping constant values 
  // in one place to know them at a glance and change them in one place etc.
  private const int NumberOfRepeats = 8;

  public void DoSomething() 
  {
    int repeatCount = 0
    while (repeatCount++ < MyClass.NumberOfRepeats)
    {
    }
  }
}
```

In your case you only have to let the `Final<T>` return the member value of the wrapped type as a read-only value. This means, the returned value itself must be immutable (an immutable reference type or struct) in case you want the returned instance to remain constant.

However, the following example shows why your idea is redundant as you always end up assigning a copy of the value to a local variable while the local variable itself is never read-only:

**C#**

```cs
public readonly struct Final<T>
{
  // Only works if T is value type
  public T Value => this.factory.Invoke();
  private Func<T> factory;

  public Final(Func<T> factory) 
  {
    // TODO::Consider to check if type is immutable using reflection in order to add robustness.
    this.factory = factory;
  }
}

class SomeMutableReferenceType
{
  public SomeMutableReferenceType(double y)
  {
    this.Y = y;
  }

  public double Y { get; set; }
}

public void Main()
{
  var mutableInstance = new SomeMutableReferenceType(12.0);
  var Final<SomeMutableReferenceType> finalValue 
    = new Final<SomeMutableReferenceType>(() => mutableInstance.Y);

  // Not allowed. Property will always return 12.0
  finalValue.Value = 3.0;

  // Allowed
  mutableInstance.Y = 3.0; 

  // Allowed!!!
  finalValue.Value = new Final<SomeMutableReferenceType>(() => mutableInstance.X);

  // However, the following code achieves the exact same behavior
  double value = mutableInstance.Y;

  // Then use value instead of mutableInstance.Y (effective final).
  // What makes your overall attempt redundant and only adds overhead.
  value = 3.0; // Does not change the original mutableInstance.Y
}
```

You may want to pass the read-only references to the consuming method by reference using the `in` keyword:

**C#**

```cs
public void Main()
{
  var mutableInstance = new SomeMutableReferenceType(12.0);

  // Allowed
  mutableInstance = new SomeMutableReferenceType(3.0);

  // mutableInstance will never get modified by the following method
  DoSomethingWithReadOnlyVaariables(in mutableInstance);
}

private void DoSomethingWithReadOnlyVaariables(in SomeMutableReferenceType readOnlyValue)
{
  // Compiler error.
  // This is the closes you can get to read-only locals in Java  
  var mutableInstance = new SomeMutableReferenceType(12.0);
}
```

### Conclusion

When looking at Java's `final` from a read-only or constant value point of view, the equivalent in C# would be the use of the `in` keyword and pass read-only variables to the consuming method. Of course, under the hoods both are completely different compiler features.

When looking at performance, it is important to know that C# supports local constants. Java doesn't.
Static compiletime values (constants) indeed offer performance benefits as they are allowed to be inlined by the compiler.

A constant *field* or local variable have several advantages compared to `final` local variables (readability, maintainability, and static compiler optimizations) and makes `final` locals redundant (which only comes with a negligible performance gain - if any at all).

When looking at `final` local variables from the perspective of the language context where they are *mandatory* to use (closures i.e. lambdas aka anonymous classes), then C# simply doesn't have those language limitations that require the introduction of such a keyword.

As another matter of fact, it was discussed by the C# language design team to implement read-only locals. They again didn't see any value.
What matters are the performance gains and those are negligible as read-only values are not static in terms of how they are interpreted by the compiler. For these special cases C# allows `const` locals.

Most people agree that cluttering your code with a `final` or `readonly` keyword for every local variable does not improve the readability.
And that following clean code principles usually leads to short compact methods that are easily understood and highly maintainable. Combine that with a carefully crafted set of unit tests and you are generally safe.

### Why `final` local variables in Java

C# closures are superior to Java closures, therefore there is no requirement of a `final` pendant.

Java didn't directly support pass-by-reference like C# does with its `ref` keyword. In Java you have to use "tricks" to achieve pass-by-reference.
Java didn't support anonymous methods like C# does with the `delegate` keyword. This all leads to a different implementation of closures like lambdas.

For Java that leads to some messy solutions in order to realize closures in Java. Because C# can directly support pass-by-reference, it is able to capture the local variable's reference.
This means, in C# changing the value of the captured variable also changes the value within the capturing scope.
In Java changing the value of the captured variable will not change the value within the capturing scope. In other words, Java closures work on copied values of variables (i.e. different memory locations) while C# closures work on copied variables (i.e. the same memory location).

Of course, the Java way does not allow for robust programming. To solve this, they had to make captured local variables read-only, to guarantee that the original and captured value copy will never get out of sync.

`final` local variables were introduced to overcome the design errors of the Java language and not to introduce read-only or constant variables. For this purpose, we have `final` and `static final` fields.
If it wasn't for those langugae design errors I doubt Java  would have `final` local variables.